# How to append a constant value to a relation in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I want to keep the tuple count of a relation to do some calculation, what is the most efficient solution. Currently i approach it like this :

```
G4 = GROUP D ALL;
E = FOREACH G4{
    total  = COUNT(D);
    GENERATE FLATTEN(D),total as total;     
};
```

the above pig code snippet translate into a MapReduce job with only one reduce  ,which is very slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This takes a long time because you have to send all your data to your reducer, and then write it all back out again to disk.  This is due to the `FLATTEN`.  The `COUNT` will actually be very efficient because Pig makes use of the combiner to work on intermediate results.  So you can compute just the count, and then efficiently `JOIN` it back in using a dummy value:

```
G4 = GROUP D ALL;
E = FOREACH G4 GENERATE COUNT(D) AS ct;
F = JOIN D BY 1, E BY 1 USING 'replicated';
```

Now your relation `F` has all of the tuples in `D`, plus a field called `ct` that is the total number of tuples in `D`.  By `USING 'replicated'`, you put `E` into memory, so you don't have to put the data through a reduce phase.

Computing `E` will still require 1 reducer, but it will be fast.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want the COUNT to be in your data's schema?
If you want to use it in later statements, then you could use the 'casting relations to scalars' feature.
A nice example is there:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-1434